# How to loop over array of structures and display all key values

Tags: arrays, coldfusion

I am looping over an array of structures and trying to assign and store all key values. If I wrap inner loop in `<cfoutput>`, I am getting an error: "Complex object types cannot be converted to simple values". If I leave it out, then it does not work. What am I missing?

[image]

```
<cfif isJSON(httpResp.fileContent)>
    <cfset jsonData = deserializeJSON(httpResp.fileContent) />    

    <cfloop from="1" to="#arrayLen(jsonData)#" index="i">
        <cfset data = jsonData[i]>

        <!---<cfoutput>--->                 
        <cfloop collection="#data#" item="key">
            #key#:#data[key]#<br>
        </cfloop>       
        <!---</cfoutput>---> 

    </cfloop>

    <cfdump var="#jsonData#">

<cfelse>
      Did not receive a valid Json object
</cfif>
```

Here is the output:

```
#key#:#data[key]#
#key#:#data[key]#
#key#:#data[key]#
#key#:#data[key]#
#key#:#data[key]#
#key#:#data[key]#
#key#:#data[key]#
#key#:#data[key]#
#key#:#data[key]#
#key#:#data[key]#
```

Comment: You need to reference specific keys inside a `cfoutput` - can be difficult when the data is not the same length each time. With structs like that you'll maybe want to use `StructFindKey()`.  If you expect similar data structure each time it should be easy enough to write conditional logic inside your loop.

Comment: I see that some of those key values are also structures themselves.  So those cannot be outputted directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> trying to assign and store all key values

While you could technically output all of the keys dynamically, if the ultimate goal is to manipulate and/or *store* the values, then dynamic looping probably isn't what you want anyway. To extract specific values, just reference the keys names explicitly - using dot-notation. For example:

```
<cfloop array="#jsonData#" index="prop">
    <cfoutput>
        <hr>confirmation = #prop.confirmation#
        <br>id = #prop.id#
        <br>label.carrier = #prop.label.carrier#
        <br>label.tracking = #prop.label.tracking#
        <br>order.created_at = #prop.order.created_at#
        <br>policy.logistic_code = #prop.policy.logistic_code#
        <br>policy.refund_code = #prop.policy.refund_code#
        <br>ref.order = #prop.ref.order#
        <br>state = #prop.state#
        ... 
    </cfoutput>
</cfloop>
```

However, to answer your question, the error message just means that `cfoutput` can only handle simple values. Since some of the values you're trying to display are actually structures (i.e. complex objects), like `label` and `states`, the `cfoutput` chokes when it tries to output them.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Your solution worked. I do have one more question. Do I have to check for key values using StructKeyEXists()? I noticed that in second element of my array there is another struct inside of one of the states. I am not sure how to attach a picture to the comment to show it.

Comment: You'd only need it if a particular key is optional (i.e. doesn't always exist). Otherwise, just use the dot notation path of the key. Notice in your original dump "states" is the top level structure => with a child key "APPROVED" => with a grandchild key "at", so the path would be:  `#props.states.approved.at#`

Comment: I updated the image in my original post. As you can see in states.refunded there are 3 keys in the second element of the array and only 2 keys in first. When I try:        `<cfif StructKeyEXists(jsonData,"totalRefunded")>
         <br>refund_amt = #i.states.refunded.transaction.totalRefunded#
</cfif>` I am receiving an error: **You have attempted to dereference a scalar variable of type class coldfusion.runtime.Array as a structure with members.**

Comment: The error is being caused by some other code. What you posted couldn't cause an error because the CFIF is never true - and the inner code `#i.states.refunded....` never even executes.  Unfortunately `StructKeyExists` can only handle a single, simple key name. To verify the nested key "transaction" exists, use `<cfif structKeyExists( i.states.refunded, "transaction")>`.  That said, while I normally never recommend `IsDefined`, checking nested keys is one of the few things it does better. Just beware of scoping issues.  Example: `<cfif IsDefined("i.states.refunded.transaction.totalRefunded")>`.

Comment: Thank you very much. IsDefined() works great. Actually both approaches you proposed work.

Comment: Just keep in mind StructKeyExists is preferred because `IsDefined()` is much more lenient about scopes and in *some* specific cases may cause issues (Lots of threads if you search on IsDefined vs StructKeyExists) So IMO, only use IsDefined() if you *really* need it ;-)

Comment: If this is CF2016, there's also the safe-navigation operator: `jsonData?.i?.states?.refunded?.transactions?.totalRefunded`. If any one of those keys doesn't exist, it will return `undefined`.

Comment: Ahh, good point! I keep forgetting about that one. Better than resorting to IsDefined, blech...